# How I can Find and Change One Word In text In php?

Tags: sql

I have a problem in sql update command. I want to change a word in a caption with sql command. For example in one coulmn I have a text , I want to change every php word with `c#`. I  use this command :

```
update tbl_name set coulmn_name=???? where coulmn_name Like "%php%"
```

please help
thanks

Comment: REPLACE() function can perhaps be used. But watch out for strings like oophpoo.

Comment: @amirprogramer Please read also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms